# Тайпхинтинг не скалярных типов

Tags: php

Я знаю что в пхп 7 появился тайпхинтинг, но раньше же его не было? Или был? Я знаю что был только небольшой тайпхинтинг для всяких там `array`, `callable` и т.п. Но случайно где-то увидел вот такое `function foo(MyClass $a)`. Это как вообще? Главное на пхп 5.6 тайпхинтинг получается любых классов вот такой работает... Совершенно случайно узнал только что. А скалярные типы все еще нельзя указывать.

P.S. Просто сижу на 5.6 сейчас и очень грустно без типов (я вообще предпочитаю статически-типизированные языки). Хочу использовать все возможности тайпхинтинга по максимуму.

Comment: обновляйтесь до php 7: [Новая функциональность](http://php.net/manual/ru/migration70.new-features.php)

Comment: @Эдуард не вариант. Сайтов сотни на хостинге. Некогда этим заниматься.

Comment: ну тогда вам придётся довольствоваться мАлым.

Comment: @Эдуард я просто хочу узнать с какой версии появилась возможность указывать классы в качестве типов аргументов функции.

Comment: посмотрите тут [Объявление типов](http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration)

Comment: круто, спасибо!